# EXCEL VBA Write - Read File - BUG?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been wracking my brains with a file input problem, I've finally got it down to two problems, I can get past the error 62, "Read past End of file", but this one I can't get past.

Can someone tell me if I'm doing anything wrong / verify?

Basically the (this) code writes two lines#

```
?xml version="1.0"?
A Second Line
```

the debug statement in Part 1 (write file) prints the text as

```
?xml version="1.0"?
A Second Line
```

the debug statement in Part 2  (read file) prints the text as

```
ÿþ?xml version="1.0"?
A Second Line
```

As you can see, there are two extra characters being added to the either the input or 
the output stream at the beginning of the file.

A second line has been added for completeness to show in more detail that it is only the first line that is being screwed.

When I look through Notepad there is nothing extra, what/where are these extras coming from?

Any thoughts, thanks in advance,
regards
Seán

```
Sub writeXMLTest()

'Part 1 - Write the file

Dim FSO As Object
Dim NewFile As Object
Dim FullPath As String
Dim XMLFileText As String

FullPath = "E:\TESTFILE.xml"
'On Error GoTo Err:

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set NewFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(FullPath, 1, 1)

XMLFileText = ""
XMLFileText = XMLFileText & "?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & "?" & vbNewLine
NewFile.Write (XMLFileText)
Debug.Print XMLFileText

XMLFileText = XMLFileText & "A Second Line" & vbNewLine
NewFile.Write (XMLFileText)
Debug.Print XMLFileText

NewFile.Close

'Part 1 - Complete

'Part 2 - Now to read the file

Dim FileNum As Integer, i As Integer
Dim s As String

' fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename

FileNum = FreeFile()
Open FullPath For Input As #FileNum

i = 1
While Not EOF(FileNum)

    Line Input #FileNum, s    ' read in data 1 line at a time
    Debug.Print s

Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: That Read output was due to **unicode** text file. It has special marker which VBA read it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick shot: Generally, xml-files use UTF8 encoding. But the `FileSystemObject` cannot handle UTF8. You can do this (read and write UTF8-Files in VBA) with an `ADODB.Stream` object - you'll find examples across the web.

Comment: Sean, this should be the reference for using ADO Streams. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677486(v=vs.85).aspx)